# How do I fix this Error trying to debug AutoHotkey script?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autohotkey

I installed AHK v2, VSCode and these AHK extensions:

AutoHotkey v2 Language Support
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thqby.vscode-autohotkey2-lsp

AutoHotKey Debug
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=helsmy.autohotkey-debug

When I try to debug the script, I get this error popup

[image]

The created launch.json looks like this

[image]

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Thanks.